# Using strtok() to parse text file

Tags: c++, file, parsing, substr, strtok

I've been trying to make a program that parses a text file and feeds `6` pieces of information into an array of objects. The problem for me is that I'm having issues figuring out how to process the text file. I was told that the first step I needed to do was to write some code that counted how many letters long each entry was. The *txt* file is in this format:

```
"thing1","thing2","thing3","thing4","thing5","thing6"
```

This is the current version of my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream myFile("Book List.txt");

while(myFile.good())
{
    string line;

    getline(myFile, line);

    char *sArr = new char[line.length() + 1];
    strcpy(sArr, line.c_str());

    char *sPtr;

    sPtr = strtok(sArr, " ");

    while(sPtr != NULL)
    {
        cout << strlen(sPtr) << " ";
        sPtr = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    cout  << endl;
}
myFile.close();
return 0;
}
```

So there are two things making it hard for me right now.

1) How do I deal with the delimiters?

2) How do I deal with "skipping" the first quotation mark in each line?

Answer (score 1):

Read in a string instead of a c-style string.  This means that you can use the handy std methods.

The `std::string::find()` method should help you out with finding each thing that you want to parse.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

You can use this to find all the commas, which will give you the starts of all the things.

Then you can use `std::string::substr()` to cut up the string into each piece.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

You can manage to get rid of the quotation marks by passing in 1 more than the start and 1 less than the length of the thing, you can also use

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use `strtok` then this code snippet should give enough to modify your program to parse your data:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="\"thing1\",\"thing2\",\"thing3\",\"thing4\",\"thing5\"";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str,"\",");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, ",\"");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

If you do not have to use `strtok` then you should use `std::string` as others have advised. Using `std::string` and `std::istringstream`:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
  std::string str2( "\"thing1\",\"thing2\",\"thing3\",\"thing4\",\"thing5\"" ) ;

  std::istringstream is(str2);
  std::string part;

  while (getline(is, part, ','))
     std::cout << part.substr(1,part.length()-2) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How would I accomplish what I have to do with using std::string? Can you walk me through?

Answer (score 1):

For starters, don't use `strtok` if you can avoid it (and you easily can here - and you can even avoid using the `find` series of functions as well).

If you want to read in the whole line and then parse it:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// defines a new ctype that treats commas as whitespace
struct csv_reader : std::ctype<char>
{
    csv_reader() : std::ctype<char>(get_table()) {}

    static std::ctype_base::mask const* get_table()
    {
        static std::vector<std::ctype_base::mask> rc(table_size, std::ctype_base::mask());
        rc['\n'] = std::ctype_base::space;
        rc[','] = std::ctype_base::space;
        return &rc[0];
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::ifstream fin("yourFile.txt");
    std::string line;
    csv_reader csv;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> values;
    while (std::getline(fin, line))
    {
        istringstream iss(line);
        iss.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), csv));
        std::vector<std::string> vec;
        std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss), std::istream_iterator<std::string>(), std::back_inserter(vec));
        values.push_back(vec);
    }
    // values now contains a vector for each line that has the strings split by their commas
    fin.close();
    return 0;
}
```

That answers your first question.  For your second, you can skip all the quotation marks by adding them to the `rc` mask (also treating them as whitespace) or you can strip them out afterwards (either directly or by using a `transform`):

```
std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(), [](std::string& s)
{
    std::string::iterator pend = std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char c)
    {
        return c == '"';
    });
    s.erase(pend, s.end());
});
```